# Two "performSegue" in same class to different Viewcontrollers

Tags: swift, button, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to go to two different VC with two different buttons. With the 'newGeneratedListBtn i only want to go to vc1. With the 'newEmptyList' button i want to go to vc3 with a bool value which works. But when i click first button 'newGeneratedListBtn' to go to vc1 I get error: "Could not cast value of type 'AppName.vc1' to 'AppName.vc3'.

Seems like when i click button to vc1 it tries to send the same values as i want to send to vc3. How can i solve this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


let value = true

//Button to VC1
@IBAction func newGeneratedListBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self)
}

//Value to send to VC2
override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

        let vc = segue.destination as! ListView
        vc.newEmptyListValue = value
}

//Button to VC2
@IBAction func newEmptyList(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "valueSender2", sender: self)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast for a specific identifier

```
override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    super.prepare(for:segue,sender:sender)
    if segue.identifier == "valueSender2" {
       let vc = segue.destination as! ListView
       vc.newEmptyListValue = value 
    }
    else {
       // it's unwindSegueToVC1
    }
}
```

as both

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self) 
performSegue(withIdentifier: "valueSender2", sender: self)
```

with call `prepare`

Comment: Thank you, but what should i insert in seque and sender? 
"super.prepare(segue:    ,sender:    )"

Comment: Nothing copy it as it's , it's irrelevant to your current problem here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is only *one* implementation of `prepare(for:sender:)`, like this:

```
override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

        let vc = segue.destination as! ListView
        vc.newEmptyListValue = value
}
```

*Both* of your segues pass through that one method. You must use a switch or other condition to figure out *which* segue this is, and send the info appropriate to that segue.

Comment: By the way, I regard this as a huge flaw in the entire storyboard architecture. Your one `prepare` becomes a massive bottleneck for every single segue from that view controller. It's nuts.